# Way to authenticate against Active Directory but without direct access to it?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

So I'm in an interesting situation. I have an application that only supports authentication via LDAP on my network and client with active directory on their network. We have a secure VPN tunnel between us.

My client won't allow me to have a one-way trust to their domain, or a read-only domain controller. They also won't allow any LDAP information to go across the VPN to or from them. They will, however, allow SAML authentication. My question is, is there any appliance or server application that can get LDAP requests and translate them to a SAML request. The idea being that this application/appliance would live on my network and use LDAP locally and only send SAML across the VPN.

Comment: You're looking for a LDAP/SAML bridge or proxy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324673/ldap-to-saml-rest-proxy

Comment: Thanks. This lead me to http://www.gluu.org/ which looks like it will do what I need.